# SQL join on equal or closest date

Tags: sql, date, join, conditional-statements, nearest-neighbor

I have two tables

Table a (1 row per id)

```
id,observation_date
a,2015-03-01
b,2015-03-03
c,2015-03-05
```

table b (multiple rows per id, but unique for each id/date combination)

```
id, insert_date, value
a,2015-02-28,x1
a,2015-03-01,x2
a,2015-03-02,x3
b,2015-02-28,x4
b,2015-03-01,x5
b,2015-03-02,x6
c,2015-02-28,x7
c,2015-03-01,x8
c,2015-03-02,x9
c,2015-03-03,x10
c,2015-03-04,x11
```

I want to join these tables on id, but also rather then joining on dates i want to join on the most recent insert date from table b in relation to the observation date in table a (where the date is either before or on the same day as the observation date)

i.e. the output should be:

```
id,observation_date,insert_date,value
a,2015-03-01,2015-03-01,x2
b,2015-03-03,2015-03-02,x6
c,2015-03-05,2015-03-04,x11
```

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 3):

A typical way of doing this uses correlated subqueries, one for each value:

```
select a.*,
       (select b.date
        from b
        where b.id = a.id and b.insert_date <= a.observation_date
        order by b.insert_date desc
        fetch first 1 row only
       ) as insert_date,
       (select b.value
        from b
        where b.id = a.id and b.insert_date <= a.observation_date
        order by b.insert_date desc
        fetch first 1 row only
       ) as value
from a;
```

Two similar methods are also available.  Use a correlated subquery to get the date and then join back to the table to get the rest of the values.  Or, if your database supports it, use lateral joins (using `apply` in SQL Server).  A more complex method involves joins and `group by`, which I don't recommend.

Note that `fetch first 1 row only` is ANSI SQL.  Your database may use something else for this purpose, such as `TOP` or `LIMIT`.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLEA TA 
INNER JOIN TABLEB TB
   ON TA.ID=TB.ID
   AND TB.INSERT_DATE = 
            (SELECT MAX(TB_E.INSERT_DATE) FROM TABLEB TB_E WHERE TB_E.ID=TB.ID AND TA.OBSERVATION_DATE >= TB_E.INSERT_DATE)
```