# Complex join with nested or subqueries in sqlalchemy - find the closest date match

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, outer-join

We have 2 tables that contain a `global_id` to join on. Let's call them `device_updates` and `client_updates`. Their respective tables (albeit reduced to help solve the problem) look like the following:

`device_updates`

| update_id | global_id | created | device_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Integer | Integer | Datetime | Datetime |

`client_updates`

| client_update_id | global_id | updated | updated_by | update_type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Integer | Integer | Datetime | Integer | String |

**Note that the real table has an Integer representing the update_type. this is just for clarity here.*

When the device changes state, it always updates the `device_updates` table. If this is an alarm state, then the client is notified and can choose to 'update' that alarm to be silenced (as an example).

What we need to be able to do is generate a history of all events from the device updates and client updates in chronological order. But since neither table is aware of each other (other than the `global_id`) I can't figure out how to ensure that each returned row contains the exact state at that point in time. Also, since there is a possibility of having a few thousand devices update each second, and a client can silence all with a single click, we can't add a column in the client updates table that references the device table row as it's both slow, and we were also planning to do bulk uploads to handle the speed requirements which means we can't assign a matched id.

As an example flow:

1. device with global_id 15 changes state
2. client 7 updates this to silence it a few seconds later
3. device with global_id 15 changes state again at some time in the future

What should be returned in an 'event_history' query is the following:

| update_id | global_id | created | device_date | client_update_id | updated | updated_by | update_type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 15 | 10:53:24 | 10:53:23 | Null | Null | Null | Null |
| 2 | 15 | 10:53:24 | 10:53:23 | 1 | 10:53:34 | 7 | "Silence" |
| 3 | 15 | 10:57:09 | 10:57:8 | Null | Null | Null | Null |

To sum up, how do I join the `device_updates` table to the `client_updates` table, but note that device updates won't necessarily have an associated client update, but all client updates will need to find the exact device update that matches the updated time (noting that the update always occurs *after* the device_date). Also note that there are potentially many thousands of devices, so it's not just for a single `global_id`.

**UPDATE**
I forgot to add an example of a query I have tried, which is below:

```
db.query(
  client_updates,
  device_updates
).outerjoin(
  device_updates, device_updates.device_update_id==db.query(
    device_updates
  ).filter(
    device_updates.global_id==client_updates.global_id,
    device_updates.device_date<client_updates.updated
  ).order_by(
    device_updates.updated.desc()
  ).first().device_update_id
)
```

But this appears to find the same `device_update_id` to match everything with.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35591480/sql-join-on-equal-or-closest-date looks close to what I need, and in some senses kind of like what I've tried, except it's raw SQL and I can't follow how it's different (other than the inner join vs left outer join)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up going with the Kafka solution. Super speedy results, as my test build was comfortably able to handle a very high throughput and I now have confidence in that being robust and fast.

Answer (score 0):

A temporary solution is to ensure that there is an id that links each row in the two tables when entering them. It's not too hard since the data coming in does have access to a unique ID. If the data is updated bt the device and needs to update the client_updates table, it uses this id. When a client updates this, they have been given that ID so their request to silence can include that ID too.
It might also be useful to just have a single history table that is the 'every data', which will ensure quick look-up.
The best alternative it to properly consider using Kafka to handle all of this.