# MySQL LEFT JOIN ON Closest Date

Tags: mysql, join, left-join, groupwise-maximum

I am trying to create a daily point-in-time table by expanding a smaller table via a join with a Range table. The Range table defines the dates for which I want to create data. The metric table holds periodically persisted data. The tables look like the following:

**Range**

| date |
| --- |
| 2000-01-01 |
| 2000-01-02 |
| 2000-01-03 |
| 2000-01-04 |
| 2000-01-05 |

**Metric**

| date | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1999-12-31 | 3.4 | 2.2 |
| 2000-01-03 | 6.2 | 1.1 |

The Dates table should define the date range by which to build the Output table. I want to join the tables on Range.date greater than Metric.date so the output looks like the following.

**Output**

| date | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2000-01-01 | 3.4 | 2.2 |
| 2000-01-02 | 3.4 | 2.2 |
| 2000-01-03 | 3.4 | 2.2 |
| 2000-01-04 | 6.2 | 1.1 |
| 2000-01-05 | 6.2 | 1.1 |

I have attempted a few different versions of this without success. Here's what I have thus far:

```sql
CREATE TABLE OUTPUT
SELECT * FROM [db].Range AS d LEFT JOIN [db].Metric AS m ON d.date > 
(SELECT m.date 
         FROM [db].Metric AS m2
         WHERE m2.date < d.date
         ORDER BY m2.date ASC
         LIMIT 1
);
```

The above returns rows for every date, metric combination where the metric is greater than the date. I could see how an outer `GROUP BY` date might solve this issue but it seems ugly and the performance will be pretty awful. Is there an easier method?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Your syntax looks like SQL Server-specific (MS SQL) and not related to MySQL. Check your DBMS carefully.

Comment: *I want to join the tables on Range.date greater than Metric.date so the output looks like the following.* Use, for example, correlated subquery in the output list.

Comment: see: [SQL join on equal or closest date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35591480/sql-join-on-equal-or-closest-date)

Comment: @Luuk - That reference seems to talk about "nearest date", where is this Question is about "preceding".

Comment: @RickJames: Is the preceding date not always the nearest date?    (Or should I really have paid more attention when someone tried to learn me some English.... )

Comment: @Luuk - I interpret "closest" or "nearest" to mean in any direction.  Eg., given "1,2,7,9", the "7" would be "closest" to "6" (also "5").  The closest to "8" would be either "7" or "9".  The "most recent" may have been a better term.  (The example data was insufficient to clarify the true intent.)  I worry that shecode's goal may be different than Ron95's.

Comment: @Luuk - And...  I accept that "closest" could imply 'preceding' in some contexts.  But I did not read anything that would imply such.  My most frustrating thing about English is how "AND" and "OR" sometimes mean the same thing.  They definitely do not mean the same thing in SQL or Math!

Comment: The 'true intent' was in the post - "The Dates table should define the date range by which to build the Output table. I want to join the tables on Range.date greater than Metric.date so the output looks like the following."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you want to join on closest date that's smaller. Have you tried:

```
Select Range.date, A, B
from Range inner join Metric
on Metric.date = (select max(date) from Metric where date < Range.date);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, a simple solution. I used a LEFT instead of INNER JOIN also.